# Find index in SortedCollection

Tags: python, indexing, sortedcollection

I use [this implementation of SortedCollection](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/).

```
>>> a = SortedCollection(key=itemgetter(1))
>>> a.insert_right(('A',5))
>>> a.insert_right(('B',3))
>>> a.insert_right(('C',7))
>>> a
SortedCollection([('B', 3), ('A', 5), ('C', 7)], key=<operator.itemgetter object at 0x028C99B0>)
```

What would be the syntax of finding the index of the item with `'A'`?
Notice that `'A'` is not the sorting key I chose.

Here's a failed way to do it:

```
>>> a.find(lambda item: item[0]=='a')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    a.find(k=lambda item: item[0]=='a')
  File "C:/dev/sorted_collection.py", line 167, in find
    raise ValueError('No item found with key equal to: %r' % (k,))
ValueError: No item found with key equal to: <function <lambda> at 0x028DB270>
```

Comment: Does this address your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946860/using-pythons-list-index-method-on-a-list-of-tuples-or-objects/946906#946906

Comment: If you need to look up items by the first item, then you should use a structure where that is the key, rather than the second item.

Comment: @agf - That was my initial thought as well, however the main function of the structure is keeping the items sorted, a collection that would include two keys - one for access and one for sorting would suite me best, alas I didn't find one and it's not worth implementing one at this point

Answer (score 1):

Tested:

```
[x[0] for x in a].index('A')
```

`SortedCollection` behaves much like a list, so it's actually the same syntax as searching in

```
[('B', 3), ('A', 5), ('C', 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = SortedCollection(key=itemgetter(1))
a.insert_right(('A',5))
a.insert_right(('B',3))
a.insert_right(('C',7))

print [y[0] for y in a].index('B')
```

**Result:**

```
0
```