# finding a specific value from list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I have the following data in my list of dictionary:

```
data = [{'I-versicolor': 0, 'Sepal_Length': '7.9', 'I-setosa': 0, 'I-virginica': 1},
{'I-versicolor': 0, 'I-setosa': 1, 'I-virginica': 0, 'Sepal_Width': '4.2'},
{'I-versicolor': 2, 'Petal_Length': '3.5', 'I-setosa': 0, 'I-virginica': 0},
{'I-versicolor': 1.2, 'Petal_Width': '1.2', 'I-setosa': 0, 'I-virginica': 0}]
```

And to get a list based upon a key and value I am using the following:

```
next((item for item in data if item["Sepal_Length"] == "7.9"))
```

However, all the dictionary doesn't contain the key `Sepal_Length`, I am getting :

```
KeyError: 'Sepal_Length'
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: This question makes me think `list.index` should take an optional `key`, like `list.sort`, to use as a predicate...

Comment: @Claudiu -- That's an interesting thought.  I use this `next` idiom pretty frequently, but it has some quarks (e.g. supplying a default value if you aren't sure that a match will be found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` to get the value:

```
next((item for item in data if item.get("Sepal_Length") == "7.9"))
```

`dict.get` is like `dict.__getitem__` except that it returns `None` (or some other default value if provided) if the key is not present.

---

Just as a bonus, you don't actually need the extra parenthesis here around the generator expression:

```
# Look mom, no extra parenthesis!  :-)
next(item for item in data if item.get("Sepal_Length") == "7.9")
```

but they help if you want to specify a default:

```
next((item for item in data if item.get("Sepal_Length") == "7.9"), default)
```