# Unable to index in Python

Tags: python, indexing, valueerror

I am trying to locate a random value from one array in another array:

```
team1Players = random.sample(activePlayers, 4)
print(team1Players[0])
index1 = overallPoints.index(f'{team1Players[0]}')
```

The above code yields the following output:

```
/Users/johnbeatty/PycharmProjects/THTTeamMakerv2/venv/bin/python /Users/johnbeatty/PycharmProjects/THTTeamMakerv2/main.py
playerName 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnbeatty/PycharmProjects/THTTeamMakerv2/main.py", line 237, in <module>
    index1 = overallPoints.index(f'{team1Players[0]}')
ValueError: 'playerName' is not in list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do not see why there should be a problem here; Python clearly recognizes the playerName and its name in the list... Would anybody be able to help me out here?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What does `overallPoints` contain? Are you sure it's a list of player names? Maybe print out the list to make sure it's containing the data you expect, or use a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in this line: `overallPoints.index(f'{team1Players[0]}'` is that you are trying to search for a player name in `overallPoints`, which is a list of tuples. You won't find any player names by themselves there. You will only find tuples.

Try this instead:

```
import random 

activePlayers = ["Jack", "Ken", "Kyle", "Donald", "Amy"]
overallPoints = [("Jack", 10), ("Ken", 15), ("Kyle", 20), ("Donald", 30), 
("Amy", 40)]

team1Players = random.sample(activePlayers, 4)
index1 = [i[0] for i in overallPoints].index(team1Players[0])
print(team1Players)
```

Some additional notes:

- If you are concerned about the speed or complexity of the proposed approach, look through this related [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946860/using-pythons-list-index-method-on-a-list-of-tuples-or-objects) for other suggestions on how to use the `.index()` function when parsing a list of tuples.
- I used the fake data above when testing my approach since `activePlayers` and `overallPoints` was not provided.
- I assumed that a player from `activePlayers` would always be present in one of the tuples in `overallPoints`.
- I assumed that player names are unique. If this is not true and the sampled player from `activePlayer` has the same name as another player that exists in `activePlayer`, then the program as is will only return the index of the first appearance of the player in `overallPoints`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `overallPoints` array does not have a value 'playerName'.

You should add the value inside `overallPoints`.

Comment: I forgot to specify— overallPoints is a list of tuples, [(playerName, x), (player2Name, y), ... (player16Name, z)]. Is there a way to index the first tuple value? Thanks for your response!